Testing a command if it exists and adding a prefix
In this file, I have a check, if a command exists. How may I add my prefix to an existing  command, to make it unique?
    \TeX
\def\prefix{mbe}
Myprefix: \prefix
\def\command#1{\ifx#1\undefined {\tt\string#1} is undefined\else{\tt\string#1} is now reserved\fi}

\command{\test}

Now defining test.
\def\test{Mytest}

Test \test

\command{\test}

\def\test#1{{\bf #1}}

Redefining test

\test{Mytest}
\bye


Do you want a copy of the control sequence where the meaning is the same but the name is prefixed by the characters coming from \prefix? I.e., if you have \foobar, then define \mbefoobar to have the same meaning as \foobar?

@Ulrich Diez I like to have the commands renamed, to be free to modify them, without getting a conflict with standards. This is not the same as \newcommand or \renewcommand., because I am using \TeX, not \Latex. In effect, I want to gain a "namespace" for my own commands, to avoid conflicts with existing commands.

Unlike "copying" renaming would conflict with the standards as after reaming a standard control sequence it would not be available under its usual name any more. So the question is: Do you wish to rename? Do you wish a prefix to be taken into account when defining from scratch and using your own macros? Do you need checking whether the token to rename/to copy actually is a single token and a control sequence? So that you could also "copy" \undefined to \mbeundefined? So that attempting to copy/rename, e.g., a non-active character a would lead to an understandable error message?

"..., because I am using \TeX, not \Latex." - the formats don't have backslashes in their names - it is "TeX or LaTeX". ;-)

note that one thing you could do would be to use a local group. as long as you stick to local macro definitions, nothing you do will affect anything outside the group. this is why it is generally (though not always) safe for people to do things like \def\a{} and \foreach \i/\j inside tikzpicture environments. (at least, it is one reason - tikz does some additional things to keep the effects of code local). obviously, things would go badly if you wanted \i or \j inside the loop. but in that case, the cause of the problem is at least usually somewhat obvious.

@Ulrich Diez About renaming or copying: If I rename a command, the same command would be available under a new name, not touching the original command, right?  After renaming, I am free to alter the command, right?
I do not see, why a renamend command would conflict with the original command at all.

@MBE "About renaming or copying: If I rename a command, the same command would be available under a new name, not touching the original command, right?" That's what I would call "copying". ;-) Analogously to the handling of files. When a file is renamed, there is still only one file, but its name is changed. When you copy a file, there are two files which have different names. The content of one file can be changed without this affecting the content of the other. I am about to write an answer, but this may take some time - struggling with English language... ;-)

@Ulrich Diez "struggling with English language." So am I. :-))

Due to the 30000 character limit this answer was split in two parts.
This is part 1.
Part 1 is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733442
Part 2 is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733443

After tokenization everything in TeX is based on so-called tokens.
Tokens exist only while the TeX program is running.
Tokens can come into being in two ways:

In the processing stage of tokenization, i.e., in the process of looking at the characters that occur in the .tex-input-file and taking them for instructions for creating explicit character tokens or gathering characters that form names of control sequence tokens and creating control sequence tokens and appending the tokens created to the token stream.
In the processing stage of expansion when expandable tokens and tokens forming their arguments or argument-delimiters get removed from the token-stream and instead of them other (or same) constellations of tokens are inserted into the token-stream.

Tokens can be divided in two classes:

The class of explicit (non-active) character tokens.

The class of control sequences.
The class of control sequences (without the word "tokens") divides into two "sub-classes":

The "sub-class" of active character tokens.

The "sub-class" of control sequence tokens (with the word "tokens").
The "sub-class" of control sequence tokens in turn divides into two "sub-sub-classes":

The "sub-sub-class" of control word tokens.

The "sub-sub-class" of control symbol tokens.
The names of control symbol tokens modulo the leading backslash-character/modulo the leading character of category 0(escape) consist of a single character which is not of category 11(letter) whereas names of control word tokens—modulo the leading backslash-character/modulo the leading character of category 0(escape)—either consist of a single character which is of category 11(letter) or consist of several characters.
So in the processing stage of tokenization, when by looking at characters that come from the .tex-input-file, right after encountering a backslash/a character of category 0(escape)  gathering characters that form the name of a control sequence token, the category of the first character of the name is the criterion by which TeX decides whether gathering the name of a control symbol token and thus ceasing gathering or gathering the name of a control word token and thus continuing gathering characters until encountering a character whose category code is not 11(letter).
When TeX writes control word tokens unexpanded to text file or to screen, it appends a space character. It does not do so with control symbol tokens.







With traditional TeX engines and XeTeX a namespace-prefix cannot be taken into account in the processing stage of tokenization in the sense that you specify a namespace-prefix and whenever you set a flag or the like for using it, the prefix is used automatically by TeX when looking at characters coming from the .tex-input file and appending tokens, e.g., control sequence tokens, to the token stream. (Maybe with LuaTeX this is possible.)
With traditional TeX engines a namespace-prefix can be taken into account when in the processing stage of expansion, i.e., in the course of replacing constellations of tokens by different or same constellations of tokens, having TeX deliver control sequence tokens. This implies that whenever you wish to define or use a control sequence token where the namespace-prefix is taken into account, that token first needs to be constructed in the stage of expansion. Thus maintaining and using a mechanism for handling namespace-prefixes requires some expertise in the subjects of tokenization and expansion.
The applying of such a mechanism to control sequence tokens that are defined in terms of \outer would require special attention.
Caveat: In the previous paragraph the term "control sequence tokens" is used. I.e., it is referred to the sub-class of control sequence tokens. A namespace-prefix does not make sense with control sequences which belong to the sub-class of active character tokens.
Caveat: Applying a namespace-prefix may imply dealing with a control sequence token whose name consists of more than one character instead of dealing with a control sequence token whose name consists of a single character. In case the single character currently does have a category differing from 11(letter) this implies dealing with a control word token instead of a control symbol token. When writing unexpanded to text-file, a control symbol token is not written with an additional trailing space while a control word token is written with an additional trailing space.
Caveat: There are some subtleties to be taken into account when it comes to reading back from external text file. Adding a prefix to the name of a control sequence token may lead to having a name which is a mixture of characters of category 11 and characters of a category differing from 11. A control sequence token whose name consists of several characters and contains at least one character that is not of category 11 at the time of unexpanded-writing is handled as a control word token. However, such a control sequence token can only come into being in the processing stage of expansion as it needs to be created via \csname..\endcsname.  This is because in the processing stage of tokenization, i.e., in the processing stage of looking at the characters that occur in the .tex-input-file and taking them for instructions for creating explicit character tokens or gathering characters that form names of control sequence tokens and creating control sequence tokens and appending the tokens created to the token stream, only characters of category 11(letter) might be taken for components of names of control word tokens.
Assume via a namespace-prefix-handling mechanism the prefix "MyPrefix" was prepended to the name of the control symbol token \ so that you got a control sequence token \MyPrefix. When it comes to unexpanded-writing to external text file, characters \MyPrefix* are written to the external text file. When reading from the external text file while the usual category régime is in effect, in the processing-stage of tokenization you don't get the control word token \MyPrefix*, but you get the control word token \MyPrefix and the explicit character token *12.
Assume via a namespace-prefix-handling mechanism the prefix "12" was prepended to the name of the control word token \three so that you got a control word token \12three. When it comes to unexpanded-writing to external text file, characters \12three are written to the external text file. When reading back from the external text file  while the usual category régime is in effect, in the processing-stage of tokenization you don't get the control word token \12three but you get the control symbol token \1 and the explicit character tokens 212, t11, h11, r11, e11, e11.
Assuming you take care to apply it in a way where the turning of a control symbol token into control word tokens and the mixing of characters of category 11(letter) with characters of a category differing from 11 within the name of a control word token does not lead to problems, you can probably implement a mechanism for handling namespaces based on a macro which as one of its argument takes a sequence of explicit character tokens denoting the non-prefix-part of the name of a control sequence token and via \csname..\endcsname produces a control sequence token whose name consists of the characters coming from expanding the macro \prefix trailed by characters passed in via the argument for denoting the name's non-prefix-part.
For this purpose a macro \PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken comes to mind which makes use of so-called #{-notation with ⟨parameter text⟩ for denoting a macro argument which is delimited by a curly opening brace of category 1(begin group).  #{-notation is described in Donald E. Knuth's TeXbook:
Syntax:
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken⟨tokens not in braces⟩{1⟨NameOfCs⟩}2
→
⟨tokens not in braces⟩\⟨prefix⟩NameOfCs
(⟨tokens not in braces⟩ may be empty.)
(Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with \expandafter.)
With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken{1f11o11o11}2 → \⟨prefix⟩foo.
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\newcommand{1f11o11o11}2... → \newcommand\⟨prefix⟩foo... .
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{1f11o11o11}2... → \DeclareRobustCommand\⟨prefix⟩foo... .
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{1f11o11o11}2... → \global\long\outer\def\⟨prefix⟩foo... .
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\expandafter{1f11o11o11}2\bar → \expandafter\⟨prefix⟩foo\bar
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let{1f11o11o11}2=12\bar → \let\⟨prefix⟩foo=12\bar
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let{1f11o11o11}2=12\foo → \let\⟨prefix⟩foo=12\foo**
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let{1f11o11o11}2=12{1b11a11r11}2 →
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let\⟨prefix⟩foo=12{1b11a11r11}2 →
\let\⟨prefix⟩foo=12\⟨prefix⟩bar
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string{1f11o11o11}2 → \string\⟨prefix⟩foo.
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\meaning{1f11o11o11}2 → \meaning\⟨prefix⟩foo.
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{1f11o11o11}2... → \NewDocumentCommand\⟨prefix⟩foo... .
With such a mechanism components of names of control sequence tokens are processed as arguments of macros whereas curly braces being components of macro arguments need to be balanced. Thus you need to do some brace-hackery if you want to handle control sequence tokens whose names consist of sequences of characters where curly braces are not balanced:
\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\def{1f11o11o11\iffalse{1\fi}2{1\iffalse}2\fi}2... →
\def\⟨prefix⟩foo}{... .
Implementation:
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from \prefix and non-prefix-part of name of 
%% control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% 
%% \PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\<prefiy>NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
%% 
\long\def\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerPrefixAndCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerPrefixAndCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\UDexchange\csname\prefix#2\endcsname{\UDstopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\long\def\UDexchange#1#2{#2#1}%
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
...
\def\prefix{mbe}

With this implementation of \PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken, the non-prefix-part of the name of the control sequence token to handle is to be given as a sequence of explicit character tokens.
If you like, you can combine this with a routine \CsTokenToString which as its argument takes a control sequence token, applies \string, and from the result removes the leading explicit character token denoting the escape-character, usually backslash of category 12(other), for obtaining a sequence of explicit character tokens denoting the name of the control sequence token in question.
If you are picky, then removing the leading explicit character token denoting the escape-character is a bit tricky.
This is because actually the result of applying \string to a control sequence token depends on the value of the integer parameter \escapechar:
Usually the value of \escapechar is 92(dec) which denotes the backslash character in TeX's internal character encoding scheme, thus \string\TeX usually gets you \12T12e12x12. But, if, e.g., the value of \escapechar is set to 65(dec), which is the number of the codepoint of the character A in TeX's internal character encoding scheme, then \string\TeX gets you A12T12e12x12.  If the value of \escapechar is 32, which denotes the space-character, then the leading character-token coming from \string denoting the escape-character will be an explicit space character token of category 10(space) which cannot be removed via "gobbling" an undelimited argument as TeX skips explicit space character tokens of category 10 when gathering the very first token of an undelimited argument. If the value of \escapechar is outside the range of numbers of codepoints provided by TeX's internal character encoding scheme, then with traditional TeX-engines and recent releases of LuaTeX and XeTeX no character token representing the escape-character is prepended at all, with old releases of LuaTeX, if the value out of range is positive, the result is sort of unpredictable. E.g., if the value of \escapechar is -12, which is outside the range of codepoint-numbers provided by TeX's internal character encoding scheme, then \string\TeX gets you T12e12x12. The range of codepoint-numbers provided by TeX's internal character encoding scheme in turn depends on the TeX-engine in use. With traditional TeX-engines TeX's internal character encoding scheme provides 256 code-points in range 0(dec)...255(dec)=0(hex)..FF(hex) whereof codepoints 0(dec)..127(dec)=0(hex)...7F(hex) comply to the ASCII-standard. With the TeX-engines XeTeX and LuaTeX the internal character encoding scheme is unicode which comprises 1114112 code-point numbers in range 0(dec)..1114111(dec) = 0(hex)..10FFFF(hex). Probably \XeTeXrevision/\directlua being defined is an indicator for detecting whether XeTeX/LuaTeX is in use.
Also be aware that there are edge cases where applying \string does not yield exactly the name of the control sequence token in question. For example, expanding \csname\endcsname yields a control sequence token whose name doesn't have any characters at all. That sometimes is referred as the nameless control sequence token. You can also obtain it by having a single backslash "\" or another single character of category 0(escape) at the end of a line of the .tex-input-file while the value of the integer parameter \endlinechar is not positive. When you apply \string to the nameless control sequence token, you get explicit character token according to the value of \escapecharc12s12n12a12m12e12explicit character token according to the value of \escapechare12n12d12c12s12n12a12m12e12.
An implementation of \CsTokenToString could be:
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\UDfirstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\UDsecondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\UDexchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UDCheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDsecondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDfirstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \CsTokenToString<control sequence token>  or
%% \CsTokenToString{<control sequence token>}:
%% -> stringification of <control sequence token> with leading escapechar
%%    removed
%%.............................................................................
\def\UDremovespace#1#2#3{%
  \def\UDremovespace#3{}%
  \long\def\UDGobbletillNameless##1#1{}%
  \long\def\CsTokenToString##1{%
    \expandafter\UDCheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UDGobbletillNameless##1#1}{%
     \expandafter\UDexchange\expandafter{\string##1}%
     {%
        \ifnum\escapechar<0 %
        \expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\else\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\fi
        {%
          \ifnum\escapechar>%
            \expandafter\ifx\csname XeTeXrevision\endcsname#2%
              \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname#2 255\else 1114111\fi
            \else 1114111\fi#3%
              \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo
           \else
             \expandafter\UDsecondoftwo
           \fi
           {}{%
             \ifnum\escapechar=32#3%
             \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
             {\UDremovespace}{\UDfirstoftwo{}}%
           }%
        }{}%
      }%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\UDremovespace\csname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi{ }%

\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\message{!!!\expandafter\CsTokenToString\expandafter{\csname\endcsname}!!!}

\escapechar=32
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=-15
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=0
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=255
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=258
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=1114111
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\escapechar=1114118
\message{!!!\CsTokenToString{\TeX}!!!}

\bye

Putting the pieces together, as a starting-point you could do s.th. like this:
%%=============================================================================
%% Infrastructure for namespace management:
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\UDfirstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\UDsecondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\UDexchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UDCheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDsecondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDfirstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \CsTokenToString<control sequence token>  or
%% \CsTokenToString{<control sequence token>}:
%% -> stringification of <control sequence token> with leading escapechar
%%    removed
%%.............................................................................
\def\UDremovespace#1#2#3{%
  \def\UDremovespace#3{}%
  \long\def\UDGobbletillNameless##1#1{}%
  \long\def\CsTokenToString##1{%
    \expandafter\UDCheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UDGobbletillNameless##1#1}{%
     \expandafter\UDexchange\expandafter{\string##1}%
     {%
        \ifnum\escapechar<0 %
        \expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\else\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\fi
        {%
          \ifnum\escapechar>%
            \expandafter\ifx\csname XeTeXrevision\endcsname#2%
              \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname#2 255\else 1114111\fi
            \else 1114111\fi#3%
              \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo
           \else
             \expandafter\UDsecondoftwo
           \fi
           {}{%
             \ifnum\escapechar=32#3%
             \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
             {\UDremovespace}{\UDfirstoftwo{}}%
           }%
        }{}%
      }%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\UDremovespace
\csname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi{ }%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Obtain control sequence token from \prefix and non-prefix-part of name of 
%% control sequence token:
%%.............................................................................
%%
%% \PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\<prefiy>NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
%% 
\long\def\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerPrefixAndCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerPrefixAndCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\UDexchange\csname\prefix#2\endcsname{\UDstopromannumeral#1}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Cosmetics:
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=\baselineskip
%%=============================================================================

\def\prefix{mbe}%

{\tt\string\prefix} yields: \prefix

\def\DefinedStatusMessage#1{%
  {\tt\string#1} is \ifx#1\undefined undefined\else now reserved\fi
}%

{\tt\string\meaning\string\test} yields: {\tt\meaning\test}\hfill\break
I.e., the control sequence token {\tt\string\test} is not assigned a meaning
yet.

{\tt\string\DefinedStatusMessage\string{\string\test\string}} yields:
\DefinedStatusMessage{\test}

Now {\tt\string\def\string\test\string{Mytest\string}} is done.

\def\test{Mytest}
{\tt\string\meaning\string\test} yields: {\tt\meaning\test}\hfill\break
I.e., the control sequence token {\tt\string\test} is a macro.

{\tt\string\DefinedStatusMessage\string{\string\test\string}} yields:
\DefinedStatusMessage{\test}

Check if {\tt\string\mbetest} is defined:

{\tt\string\begingroup\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\endgroup
\string\DefinedStatusMessage\string{test\string}} yields:
\begingroup\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\endgroup\DefinedStatusMessage{test}

Check if {\tt\string\mbetest} is defined:

{\tt\string\begingroup\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\endgroup
\string\DefinedStatusMessage\string{\string\CsTokenToString
\string{\string\test\string}\string}} yields:
\begingroup\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\endgroup\DefinedStatusMessage{\CsTokenToString{\test}}

% Copying the meaning of \test \mbetest:

The meaning of {\tt\string\test} can be copied to {\tt\string\mbetest} via%
\hfill\break
{\tt\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\let\string{test\string}=\string\test} 
or via%
\hfill\break
{\tt\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\let\string{\string\CsTokenToString
\string{\string\test\string}\string}=\string\test}.

\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let{test}=\test
%\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\let{\CsTokenToString{\test}}=\test

The meaning of {\tt\string\mbetest} can be obtained via\hfill\break
{\tt\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\meaning\string{test\string}}\hfill\break
and is {\tt\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\meaning{test}}


The meaning of {\tt\string\mbetest} can also be obtained via\hfill\break
{\tt\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\meaning
\string{\string\CsTokenToString\string{\string\test\string}\string}}\hfill\break
and still is {\tt\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\meaning{\CsTokenToString{\test}}}

{\tt\string\mbetest} can be redefined via s.th. like\hfill\break
{\tt\string\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\string\def\string{test\string}\string{redefined\string}}.

\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\def{test}{redefined}%

The meaning of {\tt\string\test} is:\hfill\break
{\tt\meaning\test}

The meaning of {\tt\string\mbetest} is:\hfill\break
{\tt\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\meaning{test}}

The meaning of {\tt\string\mbetest} still is:\hfill\break
{\tt\PrefixAndCsNameToCsToken\meaning{\CsTokenToString{\test}}}

\bye


With the infrastructure for namespace-management provided so far, \csname..\endcsname is used under the hood for creating a control sequence token from explicit character tokens (and from things that expand to explicit character tokens) that are to denote the name of that control sequence token. However, in case the control sequence token created by \csname..\endcsname does not already have a meaning/is undefined, as a side-effect TeX gives it the meaning of the \relax-primitive within the current scope. (That assignment is restricted to the current scope no matter what the value of the parameter \globaldefs is.)

TeX, for example, provides the control sequence \ifx or \def. If you define a control sequence  (for example \def\foo{...} then you can use the control sequence \foo. You want to access to \ifx, \def, \foo together in single name space. So, namespaces cannot be implemented the way you described.
OpTeX, for example implements namespaces. All TeX primitives and OpTeX macros have two control sequence names when OpTeX is initialized: \ifx and \_ifx for example. The names with _ prefix are from private namespace and the names without this prefix are in user namespace. A user can define whatever in the user namespace without affecting of OpTeX behavior, because it uses only private namespace internally. For example, a user can say \def\ifx{...}, \def\par{...} etc. without worrying about something going wrong.
Of course, if users need to access to primitive meaning of \ifx after \ifx was newly defined in the user namespace, they can use \_ifx which has always primitive meaning while \ifx can have meaning given by users. Other example: users can do \def\def{...} but if they want to define something else, then they have to use \_def\foo, because \def control sequence was re-defined.
OpTeX provides specific namespaces too. Each OpTeX package can have its own name space decared by \_namespace{xyz}. Then a package writer can use control sequences with . prefix (\.foo for example) and they are renamed internally to \_xyz_foo. So different package writers have different prefixes, but they needn't write these prefixes explicily into their code (like in expl3), they write only \.foo (after \_namespace declaration).
You can read more about the namespaces in section 2.2 of the OpTeX documentation.

If I understand correctly, you want a substitute of \def that checks whether the control sequence is defined and, in this case, it adds mbe to the name.
\def\safedef#1{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1 \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\csname\string#1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\def\else\expandafter\safedefauxi\fi#1%
}

\def\safedefauxi#1{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1 \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\safedefauxii\expandafter{\csname mbe\string#1\endcsname}#1%
}
\def\safedefauxii#1#2{%
  \immediate\write20{\string#2\space defined, using \string#1}%
  \def#1%
}


\safedef\box#1{baz#1baz}

\show\mbebox

The output on the console is
\box defined, using \mbebox
> \mbebox=macro:
#1->baz#1baz.
l.19 \show\mbebox


Due to the 30000 character limit this answer was split in two parts.
This is part 2.
Part 1 is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733442
Part 2 is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733443

Some remarks besides namespace-management:
In your question you also cope with the issue of checking whether a control sequence is undefined. The test \ifx#1\undefined relies on \undefined not having a \meaning assigned. The author of this answer already saw code where \undefined was temporarily defined. In case you cannot rely on \undefined being undefined and don't mind the test to fail for tokens defined in terms of \outer, you can probably check by parsing the \meaning of the token in question:
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\UDfirstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\UDsecondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\UDexchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UDCheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDsecondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDfirstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether token is undefined control sequence (only with undefined 
%% control sequences the \meaning has the leading phrase "undefined"; besides
%% this \meaning never delivers no tokens at all) - the argument of 
%% \UDCheckWhetherUndefined must be a single token; the argument of 
%% \UDCheckWhetherUndefined must not be empty:
%%.............................................................................
\begingroup
\def\CheckWhetherUndefined#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  \long\def\CheckWhetherUndefined##1{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDCheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UDCheckWhetherUndefined\meaning##1#1#2}%
  }%
  \def\UDCheckWhetherUndefined##1#1##2#2{##1}%
}%
\escapechar=-1\relax
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDexchange
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi{%
  \expandafter\CheckWhetherUndefined\expandafter{\string\undefined}%
}%
%%=============================================================================

\CheckWhetherUndefined{A}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\CheckWhetherUndefined{\relax}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\CheckWhetherUndefined{\UndeFINeD}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\catcode`\Z=13 \letZ=\UndeFinED

\CheckWhetherUndefined{Z}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\defZ{macro}

\CheckWhetherUndefined{Z}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\letZ=\TeX

\CheckWhetherUndefined{Z}{an undefined control sequence}{not an undefined control sequence}

\bye

Probably you are also interested in finding out whether a token is a macro. If you don't mind the test to fail in case the token to examine is defined in terms of \outer, you can test this also by parsing the \meaning of the token in question - only with macros the \meaning contains the sequence ->:
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\UDfirstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\UDsecondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UDCheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                    {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                      which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UDsecondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDsecondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\UDfirstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether non-\outer token is macro.
%% (Only with macros the \meaning contains the sequence ->) 
%% The argument of \CheckWhetherMacro must be a single non-\outer token.
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\CheckWhetherMacro#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDCheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UDCheckWhetherMacro\meaning#1->%
  }{\UDsecondoftwo}{\UDfirstoftwo}%
}%
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherMacro#1->{}%
%%=============================================================================

\CheckWhetherMacro{a}{a macro}{not a macro}

\CheckWhetherMacro{\relax}{a macro}{not a macro}

\CheckWhetherMacro{\UndeFiNeD}{a macro}{not a macro}

\CheckWhetherMacro{\TeX}{a macro}{not a macro}

\bye

With this answer there is not much error-checking implemented. To some degree this is also due to the fact that the author of this answer did not yet find a satisfying answer to the question whether there is a reliable detection routine for finding out if a given single token can be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ of a ⟨definition⟩.

Great! Thank you for this detailed elaboration.
